# How do I remove Apollo-Angular and ALL its dependeces?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, apollo-angular

After I installed apollo-angular and @apollo/client I decided that I don't want them anymore, but using "npm uninstall apollo-angular" and "npm uninstall @apollo/client" only deletes the apollo-angular and @apollo/client folders. I want to clean up my project from all Apollo related stuff.

Trying "npm uninstall" of all the other apollo folders in node_modules (apollo-cache, apollo-client, apollo-link, apollo-utilites, and many others) does absolutely nothing.

I've also tried to manually delete the folders but I had some authorization problems (also I don't think this is the right way to do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do the following:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json // or yarn.lock if you are using yarn
npm install // or yarn install
```

The problem may be in your nested dependencies.
Recreating everything should fix it

Comment: I had to manually delete all the apollo dependencies from the package-lock.json, just deleting the file wasn't enough. Done that it worked, so thanks!